# Как вернуть назад атрибут класса

Tags: jquery

```
var isEven = function(someNumber) {
  return someNumber % 2 === 0;
};
if (!isEven(count)) {
    $(this).toggleClass('my3d');
    $(".main-menu a").removeAttr("class");
    $(".main-cube").animate({top: "0%"}, 1000);
    $(".cube").css({width: "95vw", height: "45vh", transform: "rotate3d(0,1,0,0deg)", left: "0"});
    $(".side").addClass("landing-loft").css({width: "80vw", height: "100vh"});
  }
  // on even clicks do this
  else if (isEven(count) === true) {
    $(".main-menu a").attr("class");
    $(".main-cube").css("top", "10%");
    $(".cube").css({width: "600px", height: "600px"});
    $(".side").removeClass("landing-loft").css({width: "600px", height: "600px"});
  }
});
```

Верхняя часть рабочая, нижняя в принципе тоже, но при помощи `$(".main-menu a").attr("class");` не могу назад вернуть атрибут класса, чтобы кубик вращался. Как мне его вернуть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На нечетный клик сохраним значения аттрибутов `class` в `data` для каждого элемента из `$(".main-menu a")`, а на четный клик - восстановим.

```
var isEven = function(someNumber) {
    return someNumber % 2 === 0;
};
if (!isEven(count)) {
    $(this).toggleClass('my3d');
    $(".main-menu a").each(function() {
      $(this).data("storedclass", $(this).attr("class"));
      $(this).removeAttr("class");
    });
    $(".main-cube").animate({top: "0%"}, 1000);
    $(".cube").css({width: "95vw", height: "45vh", transform: "rotate3d(0,1,0,0deg)", left: "0"});
    $(".side").addClass("landing-loft").css({width: "80vw", height: "100vh"});
 } else { // on even clicks do this
    $(".main-menu a").each(function() {
      $(this).attr("class", $(this).data("storedclass"));
    });
    $(".main-cube").css("top", "10%");
    $(".cube").css({width: "600px", height: "600px"});
    $(".side").removeClass("landing-loft").css({width: "600px", height: "600px"});
 }
});
```

Comment: Таки заработало. Спасибо!!